# How do I compare two val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using JQuery to get values from a form. When I submit the form I want to make a check on that the user has enterd the same e-mail twice and that the format is correct of the email. I can't figure out how to do it. Here's my if-clause which firebug complains at:

```
   $('#subscribe_now').submit(function(event) {


    regExp = /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/;

       if(($('#email1').val().search(regExp) == -1) || ($('#email1').val() != $('#email2').val()))) 
             return false;
        }
        else
        {
             return true
        }
     }
```

How should I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That looks ok, assuming that your text boxes have ids `email1` and `email2`. Are you having problems?

Comment: assuming you are using the right ids for the input fields..that should work. However, just to make sure you're clear.. `!=` means "not equal" so the `//do things` will execute if they are *not* equal, and the `do something else` will execute if they *are* equal.  If you want to reverse that, use `==` instead of `!=`

Comment: Made an update, the claus is also trying to verify the format of the email.

Comment: @Crayon, thanks. Yes, I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#idOfForm').submit(function () {
    if ($('#email1').val() != $('#email2').val()) {
        // display error
        return false; // Prevent form submitting
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [jQuery Validate Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate) You can use rules like `equalTo()` to make your life much easier.

Comment: No, but now that I know it exist I may do that. But hopefully for this one, I can just get some answers here because I think I'm very near to have a working solution.

Comment: Yeah I'm usually not a fan of answering questions with a different route entirely, but I thought you might find it useful and helpful.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate all input that can help me. Hopfeully someone else as well who endas up on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `submit` event:

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function(){

   var errors = Array(); // used to display or alert() errors

   if($('#email1').val() != $('#email2').val()) {
      errors.push("Email verification don't match");
   }

   // do something else, like checking user login length, ...
   // and add errors to the array

   // if there are errors, don't submit
   if(errors.length > 0) {
      // display error by inserting in html, or display with alert()
      return false; // cancel event
   }
});
```